# Schema Changes History - what was ALTERed about the object?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there anyway to figure out what was altered ?

I have pull out the report with the `transactionID`, but I can't figure out what change was made exactly.

The system is SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to restore an earlier backup and compare unless you track these changes:

- in source control
- managed release scripts
- DDL triggers
- have [extended events](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630282.aspx) switched on

Even then you won't get the transaction id that was the ALTER in all techniques

Comment: Well, there was a couple changes. It will take a long time to restore a backup and compare for each change. (Now I start to use source control to keep track on every change after this incident.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for integrated source control in SSMS, might I suggest SQL Source Control, which is a tool that I product manage here at Red Gate? I'd be interested to get your thoughts on whether this would meet your needs.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/

Comment: Are you using Database Projects? If not, SQL Source Control integrates with TFS (and other source control systems) to bring source control into SSMS.